# GPIO pins and pygame

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, pygame, raspbian, gpio

I am planning on making a game with pygame using gpio buttons. Here is the code:

```
from gpiozero import Button
import pygame
from time import sleep
from sys import exit

up = Button(2)
left = Button(3)
right = Button(4)
down = Button(14)

fps = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.init()

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((1300, 700))

x = 50
y = 50

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break
    if up.is_pressed:
        y -= 5
    if down.is_pressed:
        y += 5
    if left.is_pressed:
        x -= 5
    if right.is_pressed:
        x += 5
    surface.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.circle(surface, (255, 255, 255), (x, y), 20, 0)
    pygame.display.update()
    fps.tick(30)
```

However, when I press on the X button on the top of the window, it doesn't close. Is there a possible solution for this?

**EDIT:** Everyone is giving the same answer, that I am not adding a for loop to check events and quit. I did put that, here in my code:

```
while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break
```

I have also tried `sys.exit()`.

**EDIT 2**: @Shahrukhkhan asked me to put a print statement inside the `for event in pygame.event.get():` loop, which made the loop like this:

```
while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            print "X pressed"
            break

root@raspberrypi:~/Desktop# python game.py
X pressed
X pressed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways to close the pygame window .

1. after the end of while loop simply write

   ```
    
   import sys
   while 1:
        .......
   pygame.quit()
   sys.exit()
   ```

2.instead of putting a break statement ,replace break in for loop immediately after while as

```
while 1:
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
......
```

Comment: put a print statement inside

Comment: What do you mean??

Comment: put a print("X clicked") statement inside for loop just after beginning of if body , and check if something is printed after clicking ( X ) on console.

Comment: Turns out I didn't use sys.exit() properly. After adding it it worked. I don't know why it didn't work with break though. Maybe because it was in the for and the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a event and within it you need to quit the pygame

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```